# Topics, devices and application on Watson

Tags: android

I am not sure if I understand this correctly :
On Watson IOT platform, A device can only publish on topics with fixed string format of iot-2/evt/xxxxxxxxx" and subscribe to topics with fixed string format of "iot-2/cmd/xxxxxxxx".  Given these two different string format
of publish/subscribe topics, means that a device cannot receive a published messages from another device, even through the broker as the topics are different. The only way  the second device can receive first devices's publish message is through  a application, which catches the first device's publish message and then re-publish to second device's topic.... is this true? Is this Watson's implementation or MQTT spec? is there another way without going through an application middle entity?

Answer (score 0):

Use the pubnub cloud platform for publish/subscribe model , since it provides  api with tutorials for android sdk , even i am using pubnub for my Iot application without any fixed string format , it works like a chat and is flawless with automatic reconnect feature .